# Python: CD To Linux Users Desktop

Tags: python, directory, cd

I need to change directory (CD) to a Linux user's Desktop. Now, the Linux username is a variable, so I tried having the path, but of course it wont work:

```
import os
os.chdir("/path/to/dir")
```

So I tried the following:

```
   subprocess.call("cd", "~/Desktop")
   subprocess.call("pwd")
```

But I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SIPHON.py", line 132, in <module>
    subprocess.call("cd", "~/Desktop")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 658, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

How can I cd to a user's desktop in Linux, using Python?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand `~` as actual path using [`os.path.expanduser`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser):

```
>>> os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
'/home/falsetru/Desktop'
```

---

```
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop'))
```